# Android typefont not found

Tags: java, android, fonts, android-fonts

i'm writing this post because I have a problem with android studio on ubuntu mate 17.04.
The problem is that android studio doesn't found a custom font.
I have add this font on:

```
-main
---assets
------fonts
------------myfont.ttf
```

but when i do this:

```
Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/FUTRFW.TTF");

classibutton.setTypeface(typeface);
```

i have an exception that show myfont is not found.
I attach the structure of my project:

[image: app structure]

how can i solve this??
Thanks all for the help

Comment: share your exception

Comment: here the exception   FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{sfollatigamingclan.com.destiny2wikibooks/sfollatigamingclan.com.destiny2wikibooks.MenuActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Font asset not found fonts/FUTRFW.ttf

Comment: check my below ans

Comment: nilesh i've do it just now, but same error

Answer (score 0):

try this your have to bind your **classibutton** than your can set Custom fonts to your and also
 **don't write .ttf in capital letters**

**sample code**

```
classibutton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/FUTRFW.ttf");
classibutton.setTypeface(typeface);
```

Comment: guys the same problem 
 
here the exception FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{sfollatigamingclan.com.destiny2wikibooks/sfoll‌​atigamingclan.com.de‌​stiny2wikibooks.Menu‌​Activity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Font asset not found fonts/FUTRFW.ttf

Answer (score 0):

try this,I think .ttf should not be capital

```
classibutton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/FUTRFW.ttf");

classibutton.setTypeface(typeface);
```

Comment: man not workin
 
here the exception FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{sfollatigamingclan.com.destiny2wikibooks/sfoll‌​atigamingclan.com.de‌​stiny2wikibooks.Menu‌​Activity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Font asset not found fonts/FUTRFW.ttf

Answer (score 0):

Font file name should be in small letters. So First of all you should rename your font file as "futrfw.ttf" and then

```
classibutton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/futrfw.ttf");
classibutton.setTypeface(typeface);
```

And please be sure that your folder name should be **"fonts"** (as you are using "**fonts/futrfw.ttf"** here)  and this folder must be inside the "**assets"** folder which is inside **"main"** folder.

Comment: hey, i have attached an image with my project structure... the fonts folder is under main/assets

Comment: Then rename your font file i.e,name must be in  small letters.

Comment: Then this must be problem in your font file. Dis you downloaded it from internet or is this your custom font?

Comment: Or try to rename your file as "Futrfw.ttf" i.e, first letter in capital and others in small. And one more thing you can do is :-   Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/Futrfw.ttf");

Comment: yes it's downloaded from the internet but on office it works great.

Comment: @ChristianCortese share link from where you download the fonts

Comment: @ChristianCortese Try this :-    Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/Futrfw.ttf");

Comment: here the link of the font https://www.ffonts.net/Futurist-Fixed-width.font